# Не меняется элемент Group в SimpleExpandableListAdapter. Проблема с методом getGroupView

Tags: android, adapter, expandablelistview

Для своей задачи для всех элементов `Group` в `ExpandableListView` использую xml с `TextView` и `ImageView`. Далее по некоторому признаку мне требуется некоторым элементам `Group` менять `ImageResource`в`ImageView`. Написал такой код:

```
    for (int i : fav_numbers){
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) adapter.getGroupView(i, false, null, null).findViewById(R.id.pic);
        imgView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //adapter здесь типа SimpleExpandableListAdapter
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Код выполняется, но никаких изменений не происходит (изображение на элементах остается прежним). Есть ли какие-то ошибки в вызове метода `getGroupView` (подозреваю что может быть проблема в **null,null**) или нужно делать это каким-то другим способом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Менять разметку адаптера надо внутри адаптера, а не снаружи.

1. В методе `getGroupView` нужно по какому-то условию ставить разные картинки.
2. Условие должно быть в списке (`ArrayList`) данных.
3. В нужный момент меняйте условие в этом списке и уведомляйте адаптер об изменениях. `notifyDataSetChanged()`
4. У адаптера вызовется метод `getGroupView` и согласно изменившемуся условию разметка будет изменена.

Comment: А можно ли как-то обойтись без переписывания метода? notify я использовал далее, но все так же никакого результата (
Просто вот такая вещь `list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ImageView imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);
                imgView.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.star_big_on);
                return true;
            }
        });` спокойно работает

Comment: То есть даже при вызове через событие ExpandableListView а не адаптера срабатывает

Comment: @Vsevolod, у вас в `GetGroupView` назначается картинка? Если да, то после цикла назначается старая. А вообще - предложенны мной способ - правильный. И менять что-то через вызов `GetGroupView` - не правильно.